# Installing Ubuntu over ubuntu netbook?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-netbook

My brother a couple months ago bought a netbook and installed ubuntu netbook on it.  He later realized that he did not really use the Asus EEE netbook and wanted to sell it. He said I could have it for 100 dollars.  The problem is he said that Ubuntu netbook is very limiting.  Is it?  I did not like the simplified interface, so I decided I was going to install a full desktop version of Ubuntu on it.  I downloaded the zip file and put it on my flash driver after unzipping it.  I then set the boot order to be from the flash drive and then I booted the machine.   The screen was black and then some text appear.  It flashed to quickly for me to read all of it, or any of it.

Was my download and unzip corrupt?  Can you not install Ubuntu desktop over Ubuntu netbook?  If you can how would you?  I am very new to Linux but I want to learn it for a class and my own personal reasons.

Thank you

PS: Because the text flashed by so fast I was unable to know what to google to help.  For my class and my college projects I am working with blender and java

Comment: Just unzipping some files onto a usb key doesn't make it magically bootable. There's some preparation involved to take an ISO image (as you most likely downloaded) and make it bootable on a key. But otherwise, there shouldn't be any trouble installing it over the netbook edition. You'll probably lots of useless files leftover wasting space, but things should "just work" if Ubuntu has drivers for all the hardware in the netbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install Ubuntu over Ubuntu Netbook, however bear in mind Netbooks are not very powerful - running a full Ubuntu install may be too much for them.

If you wish to proceed, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick for instructions on how to install from a USB drive - there is a little more to it than simply unzipping  and copying it to the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would work better with a CD version. I'd try it using an USB CD-drive.
Also change the boot sequence in the BIOS.
I seriously doubt that all you have to do is unzip it to the flash drive. I imagine there must be some proper procedure to make the thumbdrive bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes get a new image downloaded. Follow the guidance above on how to create a USB image..it is not that hard to do and you can do it on another pc if you cannot get your netbook to start.

There is a application for windows or mac or linux that will help you download and create a bootable/installable USB pen drive from unetbootin here
[unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

That is fairly easy and should get you a bootable usb pen drive from which you can install on your Asus eee netbook fairly easily

Alternatively if you can get ubuntu direct from UBUNTU which is probably just as easy here which you can do if you still have windows working on your netbook and it will install ubuntu side by side alongside windows so you can give it a go.

[Ubuntu Windows Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer)

Have a go and see how you get on and let us know if either work for you and also what you think of ubuntu on your Asus :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step in [the ubuntu donwload](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) page:

1. Download Ubuntu
2. Burn your CD or create a USB drive :

   Select:

   - I would like to create a USB stick
   - To create it, I will be using: select the operation system in which you are going  to create the USB image
   - click on show me how
3. Try it!
4. if you like it! Install it!

Answer (score 0):

Can you log in to the computer? If so, `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` should do the trick. When you log in after clicking your user name, click the drop-down menu "Sessions" and select Ubuntu Desktop.